# Jmeter - Checking for duplicates values in JSON array

Tags: json, jmeter

I have an http response with JSON array

```
 {"message":"SUCCESS","possibilities":
[{"type":"title","value":"Mercedes-Benz FashionWeek New York"},
{"type":"title","value":"Mercedes-Benz FashionWeek New York"},
{"type":"title","value":"Mercedes-Benz FashionWeek New York"},
{"type":"title","value":"Chicago Fire vs. New York City"},  
{"type":"title","value":"New York Mets vs. Philadelphia Phillies"},  
{"type":"title","value":"New York Knicks vs. Detroit Pistons"},  
{"type":"title","value":"Baltimore Orioles vs. New York Yankees"},  
{"type":"title","value":"New York Mets vs. Philadelphia Phillies"},  
{"type":"title","value":"Tampa Bay Rays vs. New York Yankees"},  
{"type":"title","value":"Tampa Bay Rays vs. New York Yankees"},]}
```

I need to verify there are no duplicates titles (in my example, the first 3 results are duplicates).

What is the best way to do it in Jmeter?

- If it makes it easier, the 10th result can't be the same as the first one for example, so it's possible to compare between a title to the previous one (for example, if the 3rd title is equal to the 2nd one)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Use the [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) to capture all the values as an array. The JsonPath expression you would use is `$..value` This will return an array of values.

Step 2. Use a beanshell post-processor to iterate through the array and check for duplicates. Since you've said the list is effectively already sorted, you only have to perform n-1 comparisons for n values.